# How does MATLAB's ode45 handle highly coupled ODEs (where y' depends on x' and x' depends on y', etc.)?

Tags: matlab, ode, nonlinear-functions

If I have two sets of highly coupled ODEs such as:

```
dy/dt = A*dx/dt + B*y + C*x
dx/dt = D*dy/dt + E*y + F*x
```

or if I have a system like:

```
U = function(dy/dt)
dy/dt = function(U,...)
```

How would ode45 normally handle this? If I were to do the following:

```
DY(1) = A*DY(2) + B*y(1) + C*y(2)
DY(2) = D*DY(1) + E*y(1) + F*y(2)
```

or similarly for the second problem:

```
U = A*DY(1) + ...
DY(1) = B*U + ...
```

and run ode45, MATLAB produces results without complaint but I'm slightly hesitant as I'm not sure how it's handling such a coupled system of equations. And suggestions?

Comment: MATLAB shouldn't be able to solve this sort of problem with ode45 as it's generally an implicit problem (example number 2 provided above). It should give me an error when I try to run it, however, it runs smoothly and that's what's confusing me. Realistically I should only be able to use ode15i for this sort of problem...

Comment: Unless `DY(2)` is initialized, Matlab will cough up an error, otherwise Matlab is going to use some pre-determined value, not necessarily the value you want.

Comment: What predetermined value is it going to use though? DY(2) is not defined anywhere in the program which is what's confusing me.

Comment: Give me a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and then get back to me

Comment: After reading through all the lines of code, I know exactly why it's accepting it without complaint. When you're running a system of ODEs in MATLAB, you have to initialize a column vector with DY = zeros(N,1) where N is the number of equations. When you initialize it, it continuously uses those values throughout the solution process for implicit situations.